# Can't get comments authors via Facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm fetching a list of comments from a fanpage post. I'm using that fanpage access token and for some reason I can't get the "from" field on comments - when I list it in the graph api explorer I get "Field is empty or disallowed by the access token".

It worked like month ago and now the same thing isn't. I didn't notice any changelog entries about it. What could be the problem?

Comment: did you debug the token? is it really a page token of that page?

Comment: Type Page, has Page ID and so on and is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found: it has to a page access token but also a token with an Facebook application selected - you have to give manage_pages permission and in the long run that will have to be reviewed to allow accessing that user data.